# how to open a local html file from a program

Tags: html, for-loop, local

I'm trying to open a local html file from a program. Opening it from the web works, but I want to get it from local files (the website I'm getting it from is going to be deleted).

I had the following code in my xml file:

```
<xsl:if test="labelnumber!=''">
     <tr>
      <td class="celllabel" width="10%" nowrap="1">
       <xsl:value-of select="'Lyrics'/@label"/>
      </td>
      <td class="cellvalue">
   <a href="{labelnumber}"><xsl:value-of select="'--- klik hier ---'"/></a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:if>
```

the value of "labelnumber" is a url, generated from the program, in the same program there is a link, when clicking on it it opens the browser and shows the file. I want to do the same thing, only now that the file thats opens is a local html file.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't very clear. What is the program? If the labelnumber is a URL and you want to open it locally rather than via the web, then maybe you'll need to modify the url string, replace 'https: //www.website.com/my_html.html' with 'c:\path_to_files\my_html.com' then it'll open it locally? Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: the program is Collectorz.com Music Collector.

Labelnumber is indeed a URL, opening via the web works perfect. Then the URL is (for that album, changes for every album ofcourse): https ://lyrics.fandom.com/wiki/Saturday_Night_Fever_(1977)''

When trying it local, then the url is: file:///C:/Users/Hendrik/Documents/Nieuwe%20map/details/26876.html

That url don't do nothing, no reaction whatsoever.

Comment: So if you locate the file locally and double click it, does it open in a browser with that exact file path (for example)? Can you open .html files by double clicking them normally from File Explorer? What is in that 26876.html file? Where did this 26876.html come from? And how is it connected to the URL? Is the URL the exact same HTML as the local file?

Comment: when I click the file///…. it opens without problem in my browser (as well in Edge, Chrome as Firefox). I can open html files normally from Explorer. That 26876.html file is a file generated by the Music Collector program (option: export to html). This has in it a normal "web page": a few jpeg's, text. And how it is connected to the URL... the URL I put into the program (what makes it "labelnumber") is a simple copy/paste from the url I see in the browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help, this looks to be a specific workings of Collectorz.com Music Collector problem. Perhaps edit to to add some more detail - images of things, step-by-step what you have done so far, pad it out, this is too lean and obscure and difficult to work out what you are trying to do (hence lack of replies), and change the topics/categories, this isn't really a for-loop, or even HTML question really. Good luck.